# @Ajax.ActionLink in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: asp.net-core

In ASP.NET MVC, I can easily use Ajax.ActionLink to post back to controller with parameter

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Search Action", "SearchAction", null, new { parameter = abc }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "list" })
```

How can I perform the same like above code in ASP.NET CORE? Thanks.

Comment: Adding this feature to ASP.NET Core was under consideration, but the team ultimately decided [not to add it](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2015#issuecomment-260730609).